# Sql select distinct by one column and result from two tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

My Query is :

```
  select ab.ID, cd.code_text  
  from city ab, codes cd 
  where ab.code = cd.code;
```

But its returning duplicate values.
So I have to use distinct on code_text column.
Could somebody help me how to use distinct in this condition on code_text column ?

Comment: In the first place, in which columns do you have duplicated values before you decided to use distinct on the code_text column?

Comment: in code_text column. Thatss why I want to use distinct on code_text column.

Comment: From your comments on some of the answers, it seems as though you may have many valid city ID values for each code_text value, yet you only want to see code_text once. What do you want to do with the ID values? Can we remove them from the query altogether? If not, do you want to see the largest or smallest corresponding ID value, do you want to see all applicable ID values stuffed into a single string on the same line, or is there some other way you want to deal with the ID values?

Comment: This thread has lots of comments which indicates you probably haven't framed it well.  Please *edit your question* to explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, including some sample data and expected output, plus the business rules you want to apply to turn the one into the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>select distinct cd.code_text, ab.ID
      from city ab, codes cd 
      where ab.code = cd.code;</strike>

**Edited**

```
Select ID, "Code Text" From (  
Select ID, "Code Text", RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "Code Text" ORDER BY ID) "The Rank"
From(
select ab.ID as "ID", cd.code_text as "Code Text"
from city ab, codes cd  
where ab.code = cd.code))
where "The Rank" = 1
```

Comment: This is valid in most SQL dialects, but under Microsoft Access `DISTINCT` cannot be used this way.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd : Not Working. this will give distinct records based on two columns.

Comment: could you give some data entry of your tables so I Can see what the appropriate result you want to have ? OR at least a table of what you have as result and what you want.

Comment: This is syntactically correct under Access, but as @Peter notes, it will apply `DISTINCT` to both columns. (My initial comment was in response to using `DISTINCT(cd.code_text)`, which works in T-SQL).

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd : its fetching like this :           **ID**   **code_text**                                                                                                                                          1             newjersey                                                                           2          newjersey

Comment: I don't think that your querry is significant or logic : if you try to extract distinct  values of the `cd.code_text` values, there will always as rows as muching between the `ab.code = cd.code`.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: requirement is like this . code can be repeated many times.

Comment: I guess that in the `City` Table you have, let's say, two rows **(ID, Code)** like **(1, 5)** and **(2, 5)** where in the `codes` table **(code_text, code)** like **('newjersey, 5)** so there will always two matching rows the one where the `code = 5` so distinct have no logical issue.

May I ask you what result want you to have in such case?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd : In this case It will return 2 rows.                                                             1     'newjersey'                                                            2       'newjersey'                                                 But I want only one row with value newjersey.

Comment: so let's say any one among those two rows at random !!! there is no prefrence last or first.

Comment: @Peter : please see the Edited part !!!

Comment: @Peter: If you only want to see 'newjersey', what do you want to do with IDs 1 and 2? Can we just remove them altogether?

Comment: @MarkBannister : I think he want to keep the first one of each group of the same `code_text`

Comment: Working.. :) Great guys.. Thank you all for your precious time...

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: Surely you could achieve the same result much more simply with `select min(ab.ID), cd.code_text from city ab join codes cd on ab.code = cd.code group by cd.code_text` ?

Comment: @MarkBannister : Yes it is right what you said. I was thinking in something like First/Last so that is why I ended up with Rank. A longer way :) min and max are better.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT ab.ID, cd.code_text
FROM city ab, (
    SELECT DISTINCT codes.code, codes.code_text
    FROM codes
) AS cd
WHERE ab.code = cd.code
```

Comment: Not Working. I am using Oracle 11g and its not working. It giving error : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but please define "not working".

Comment: Do you need a `;` at the end?

Comment: Oracle does not allow using `AS` for a table alias. If you replace `AS cd` with jus `CD` it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see distinct values of code_text from the codes table, the simplest way to do it is:

```
select distinct code_text from codes
```

If you want to see distinct values of code_text from the codes table where the codes exist on the city table, the simplest way to do it is:

```
select distinct cd.code_text  
from city ab
join codes cd on ab.code = cd.code
```

- although a more efficient way in Oracle *may* be:

```
select distinct cd.code_text  
from codes cd 
where exists
(select 1 from city ab where ab.code = cd.code)
```

If you want to see distinct values of code_text with the lowest corresponding value of ID, the simplest way to do it would be:

```
select min(ab.ID), cd.code_text  
from city ab
join codes cd on ab.code = cd.code
group by cd.code_text
```

If you want to see all applicable ID values stuffed into a single string on the same line for each given code_text value, the simplest way in Oracle 11 is:

```
select listagg(ab.ID, ',') within group (order by ab.ID) IDs, cd.code_text  
from city ab, codes cd 
where ab.code = cd.code
group by cd.code_text
```